¿Cómo verificar si el usuario no ingresó nada en un joptionpane?
Tengo un joptionpane al cual le realicé un Integer.parseInt para pasarlo de String a int y quiero hacer que si el usuario no ingresa nada le salga una ventana de error. Lo intente con un isEmpty() pero al ser un dato int no me funciona.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numero=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un numero."));
    
    //validar si el campo esta vacio
    
    System.out.println(numero);
    
}

